# Copy data from sheet to the last row of another workbook

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy columns `A2:K` (or: all data on sheet apart from row 1) to a completely different workbook and paste in the last row every time (this way I can keep running the script and it won't overwrite any previous pasted data).

Here is my code:

```
function dataLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  var ss = target.getSheetByName("Copy Of DataInput");
  var vs = ss.getRange('A2:K').getValues();
  ss.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

I'm getting an error on line 6:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange') dataLog @ Untitled.gs:6`

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75162175/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, maybe you're trying to access a sheet that doesn't exist and that's why it is returning null. Make sure the sheet names `Data Sheet` or `Copy Of DataInput` are spelled correctly and it does exist in your Spreadsheet. Tested the script and made a couple of updates and it works. You can try the following:

```
function dataLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
  var vs = ss.getRange('A2:K').getValues();

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
  var ss2 = target.getSheetByName('Copy Of DataInput');
  ss2.getRange(ss2.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```